# Use CAS instead of synchronized

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized, compare-and-swap

Recently, I came across a situation when creating a factory producing reusable instances.

```
public class Factory {
    private static final int REUSABLE_TIMES_LIMIT = 10;
    private static Product instance = new Product();
    private static int getTimes;

    public static synchronized Product getInstance() {
        if (++getTimes >= REUSABLE_TIMES_LIMIT) {
            return nextInstance();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public static synchronized Product nextInstance() {
        getTimes = 0;
        instance = new Product();
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Since `getInstance()` and `nextInstance()` might both be invoked concurrently by different threads in my case, I choose to add `synchronized` key words before each of them. However, `synchronized` is too heavy when lots of threads comes to the method, so I'd like to rewrite this class based on `CAS`, i.e. those classes in the package of `java.util.concurrent.atomic`. Unfortunately, I didn't figure out a proper way to arrange my code with two atomic variables, namely `instance` and `getTimes`, in the same time. Will someone show me how to correctly use `CAS` instead of `synchronized` without causing race condition in this situation? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Is `new Product()` an expensive operation?

Comment: @shmosel yes, that's why i choose to reuse the product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one possible option is to use one AtomicReference instead of two. This will make your state consistent regardless of the code compexity.

```
public static class ProductStorage {
    private Product product;
    private int getTimes;

    public ProductStorage(Product product, int getTimes) {
        this.product = product;
        this.getTimes = getTimes;
    }
}

public static class Factory {
    private static final int REUSABLE_TIMES_LIMIT = 10;
    private static AtomicReference<ProductStorage> instance = new AtomicReference<>(
            new ProductStorage(new Product(), 0)
    );

    public static Product getInstance() {
        ProductStorage current;
        for(;;) {
            current = instance.get();
            if(current.getTimes >= REUSABLE_TIMES_LIMIT) {

                instance.compareAndSet(current, new ProductStorage(new Product(), 0));
                continue;
            }
            if(current.getTimes < REUSABLE_TIMES_LIMIT) {

                if(instance.compareAndSet(current, new ProductStorage(current.product, current.getTimes + 1))) {
                    return current.product;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The first thing you may mention is that new object is always allocated in that case. But remember that most of lock-free algorithms do that and it's not a problem. Allocation in java is fast and costs a few nanoseconds. You may also see similar solution in [Martin Thompson's blog](http://mechanical-sympathy.blogspot.ru/2013/08/lock-based-vs-lock-free-concurrent.html). The code is [here](https://github.com/mjpt777/rw-concurrency/tree/master/src). On my machine lock-free solution runs 3-4 times fastrer.

If may want to go with two atomics, but that will make counting of getTimes hard.

Comment: The logic inside the loop could be simplified a bit: `ProductStorage current = instance.get(); ProductStorage next = current.getTimes >= REUSABLE_TIMES_LIMIT ? new ProductStorage(new Product(), 1) : new ProductStorage(current.product, current.getTimes); if (instance.compareAndSet(current, next)) return next.product;`

Comment: In Java 8, the whole method can be replaced with `return instance.updateAndGet(current -> current.getTimes >= REUSABLE_TIMES_LIMIT ? new ProductStorage(new Product(), 1) : new ProductStorage(current.product, current.getTimes + 1)).product;`

Comment: @shmosel That's realy good, i havnen't seen it yet. Suggest an update?

Comment: Thanks quite a lot to both of you:)! Is there a better way to avoid creating Product in the for loop, since the cost for creating such an object is a little bit high?

Comment: @dawnwords Right now i can't see any solution that avoids allocation in a for loop. There are several options here. The first(and the easiest) option is to make Product class lazy initialized when it will be touched by consumers. In that case allocation(constructor) still will be cheap and you can discard objects. The second solution is to use pool of Product instances. In that case you don't allocate new object but claim it for use from the pool. If CAS is failed then you just return claimed object back to the pool.

Comment: @dawnwords With object pool you also can preallocate several instances of Product at once. Or you may reinitialize stale instances. The internal of object pool can be lock-free queue.

Comment: @AndreyCheboksarov lazy initialized is possible solution, I think:) Just now, I thought of the concept of Optimistic Lock. Just do it and check what you've done didn't offend others. That's also the key point of CAS. In this case, Just allocate the object, right? Thanks quite a lot!

Comment: @dawnwords Yes, you can use StampedLock in that case. But right now i can't see if solution exists which provides exact count of usage of one particular instance. Let me make it clear. First you do optimistic read, then you should update getTimes somehow. If getTimes is greater than REUSABLE_TIMES_LIMIT, then you acquire write lock, it's ok. But how do you increment getTimes consistently with instance field? In lock-free programming it's always hard to maintain two or more fields consistently only with CAS.

Comment: @dawnwords For example, some queues do not maintain size field by design because it's hard and sometimes it's not even possible to determine how many elements are in queue. Because it's lock-free. See ConcurrentLinkedQueue, for example. You have essentially the same problem. Also be aware that StampedLock has its specific. As official doc says "Optimistic read sections should only read fields and hold them in local variables for later use after validation.". But i think for immutable objects it should be ok.